# How do I change default location for new outlook pst files?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I would like to know how to change the default .pst **outlook 2010** file location of new .pst file when create a new e-mail account, ie not user C:\Documents and Settings\ .... .pst, but under a specific folder ie F:.....pst

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These 2 methods are for earlier versions of Outlook but should also work for Outlook 2010.
Reference is Microsoft Support Article [883401](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883401/)

Method 1: Add the ForcePSTPath string value to the registry
Important This section, method, or task contains steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore the registry, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: 
322756  (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756/ ) How to back up and restore the registry in Windows

To change the default path that Outlook uses for a .pst file, add the ForcePSTPath string value to the registry. To do this, follow these steps:
Quit Outlook.
Click Start, and then click Run.
In the Open box, type regedit, and then click OK.
Locate and then select the following subkey in the registry.

Outlook 2003
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook
Outlook 2002
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Outlook
With the Outlook subkey selected in step 4, point to New on the Edit menu, and then click String Value.
Type ForcePSTPath, and then press ENTER.
With the ForcePSTPath string value selected, click Modify on the Edit menu.
In the Value data text box, type the drive letter and the full path of the location that you want Outlook 2002 to use when it creates or opens a .pst file, and then click OK.
Back to the top
Method 2: Use the CIW
If you are a network administrator and want to specify a different location for using .pst file on a user's computer, you can specify the location for the .pst file in the CIW. To do this in the CIW, use the Change Office User Settings pane of the CIW.

For more information about the CIW, visit the following Microsoft Web site
http://www.microsoft.com/office/ork/xp/appndx/ciwref.htm (http://www.microsoft.com/office/ork/xp/appndx/ciwref.htm) 
For more information, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base: 
896591  (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896591/ ) You cannot specify a separate folder to store the .ost file when you use the ForcePSTPath value in Outlook 2003